# How do I find the iostream header file in a Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I was learning more about header guards in C++ from [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/1-10a-header-guards/). One of the paragraphs there said:

> Even the standard library includes use header guards. If you were to
>   take a look at the iostream header file from Visual Studio, you would
>   see:
>
> ```
> #ifndef _IOSTREAM_
> #define _IOSTREAM_
>
> // content here  
>
> #endif
> ```

I'm interested in finding the iostream header file to see this header guard myself and to learn more about how C++ directories are structured to find files like these. I had a working C++ project in Visual Studio 2015, and in the project directory I tried `dir *iostream* /s` in cmd, but I didn't find anything. How can I find the iostream header file in a Visual Studio 2015 project if it's accessible?

Comment: I'm guessing it's somewhere in `AppData` or `ProgramData` or similar. VS only stores one copy of `iostream.h` on your computer and then when you include it, it will look in that directory and include as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iostream` is not part of your project. It's part of c++ standard library. How about searching your HDD for it?

Comment: Ya, that worked. I did `dir \iostream /s`, got a match in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include`. Interestingly, I got a lot of other matches too, like from the Panda3D and Matlab folders. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: If anyone is looking for it Visual Studio 2019, you should be able to find iostream and anything else you would care to investigate from the standard library here:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333"